# Dynamically Register Widget Areas in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to allow my user to set the number of widget areas they want available for use. I've set up an options panel that lets them input the number, then set up my widget registration function to use a for loop to register that number of widget areas. This works, except that every time I go back to the widget admin area, the widget areas are all empty, regardless of what I've put in them.

Here's the code I'm using to create the widget areas:

```
function fivepints_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'fivepints' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar-1',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
        'after_widget' => "</div>",
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Home Sidebar', 'fivepints' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar-2',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
        'after_widget' => "</div>",
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );

$fp_theme_options = get_option( 'fp_theme_options'); //get number from options panel

if ($fp_theme_options['fp_sidebars'] == ""){$num = 1;} //set number to 1 if options panel value isn't set
else {$num = $fp_theme_options['fp_sidebars']; }

for ($i=1; $i<=$num; $i++) 
  {
$sidebarName = 'Sidebar ' . $i;
$sidebarID = 'fp-sidebar-' . $i;
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( $sidebarName, 'fivepints' ),
        'id' => $sidebarID,
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
        'after_widget' => "</div>",
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );

  }
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'fivepints_widgets_init' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed, if I put a widget in one of the first two widget areas (Home, or Main) and leave the others empty, the widgets disappear when the widget admin is reloaded. If I put a widget in one of the dynamically generated areas, then the admin behaves as normal. I would still like to be able to leave the dynamically generated areas empty (in case the end user decides to do that).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had to use sidebar-a and sidebar-b for the id of the static widget areas.